# An empty merge commit can let me remerge

Tags: git

I have a `staging` branch where for error I got an empty merge commit from `feature/amazing`.
Now i want to merge `feature/amazing` in `staging` but I cannot since git tells me that is all up to date. What do I have to do?

Comment: Can you provide the commands you used? How did you get an empty merge commit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get rid of the unwanted merge commit you can do,

```
git reset --hard <sha of the commit you want to point the HEAD to>
```

in the staging branch.
Usually it's the commit below the merge commit. You can get it by `git log`.

`--hard` will lose all the changes in the mentioned commit so use it wisely or you can use --soft.
Then you can do your modification in the `feature/amazing` branch and merge it again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, definitely you cannot re-merge it because you have already merged it, and created a "merge commit". But your problem is you created an empty commit message.

You can replace that empty commit message with a new one by running the following command.

```
git commit --amend -m 'your new commit message'
```

[Git manual page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#git-commit---amend) explains this feature:

```
--amend
    Replace the tip of the current branch by creating a new commit. The
    recorded tree is prepared as usual (including the effect of the -i and
    -o options and explicit pathspec), and the message from the original
    commit is used as the starting point, instead of an empty message, when
    no other message is specified from the command line via options such as
    -m, -F, -c, etc. The new commit has the same parents and author as the
    current one (the --reset-author option can countermand this).


    It is a rough equivalent for:

        $ git reset --soft HEAD^
        $ ... do something else to come up with the right tree ...
        $ git commit -c ORIG_HEAD

    but can be used to amend a merge commit.
```

This command is the equivalent of resetting and committing your work again, but just in one command. It actually combines your new commit message and the last one to create a new commit (means, you will get a new hash). Also, if you have staged changes, they will also be added to the new commit.

You should really be concerned about rewriting the history if you have already pushed your empty commit to a remote.

I hope it helps :) feel free to ask if you want to know more.